# Databinding to a string derived from the Count of a List

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a `TextBlock`, I'd like to databind it to the count of a `List<T>`.  Sort-of.

I can databind it like this:

```
<TextBlock Name="tbAlerts" Text="{Binding Path=Alerts.Count}" />
```

where Alerts is a `List<String>`, and it displays the correct thing. But, I'd like to display "No alerts" when the count is zero.

I thought a way to do this would be to extend List in order to expose an additional string property – call it `CountText` – that emits the desired string.  It might emit "No Alerts" when count is zero, and "One alert" when `Count==1`.  Will that work?

If I do this, how would I get the change in Count to result in a `PropertyChanged` event for `CountText`, so that it will get updated in the WPF UI?

is that the preferred way to get the effect I want?

Comment: Does it have to be `List<T>` or can you use another collection (like `ObservableCollection<T>`)? Also what should the displayed text be for `Count == 2` etc.?

Comment: IValueConverter (the answer given below) is the best practice to do exactly what you want. It changes a known value (a number or some such) to a display value, and back again. Then concerns of data and display remained separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish that is to create a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that would return a string if the value is zero and/or any other number that you want to add custom text to. As for the updating the UI when the count changes, you will have to call the PropertyChanged handler on the list whenever an item is added/removed from the Alerts list.

```
public class AlertCountConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            int count = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
            if (value == 0)
               result = "No Alerts";
            else
               result = count.ToString();
         }
         return result;

     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         return new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <local:AlertCountConverter x:Key="AlertCountConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<TextBlock x:Name="tbAlerts" Text="{Binding Alerts.Count, Converter={StaticResource AlertCountConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides the Converter solution, you could also do it directly in Xaml by changing the `Text` property to "No Items" when you have no items in the list

```
<TextBlock Name="tbAlerts">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Alerts.Count}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Alerts.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No Items"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: i always forget about this until i see it on stackoverflow.  i need to start doing this instead of writing a bunch of converters.