# How do I get a textbox value to be tied to the count of a List<int>()

Tags: c#, wpf

So if I have 5 values in the List the textbox says "5".

What is the best way to do this?

Specifically, in the code behind, the count of 'lister' would show up in textBox1.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<int> lister = new List<int>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lister.Add(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289713/databinding-to-a-string-derived-from-the-count-of-a-list

Comment: First off, are you referring to an actual list of objects, a List control (though actually, the List control should be tied to an underlying list of objects anyway).

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**
If you want to bind to the list itself (and not a `ListBox`) you can do the following:

1. Change your collection to be an `ObservableCollection<int>`
2. Expose it as a public property

   `public ObservableCollection<int> Lister { get; private set; }`
3. Use the following binding

   `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Lister.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />`

This binding says "locate the first parent of type `Window` and look for the public `Lister` property on it"

Making the property an `ObservableCollection<T>` means that it will automatically notify the view when it is changed.

**Original:**
No need to use the code behind at all.  Just use the below in the XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=MyListBox}" />
```

This way the Binding framework takes care of everything, and you never need to manually "refresh" the value in the text block.

Comment: But I want to bind to a List<int> in code, not to a ListBox in the XAML.

Comment: @marseilles84 yes it was - apparently SO doesn't like code within lists

Answer (score 1):

Change Lister to an ObservableCollection exposed by a public property and make sure it's initialized somewhere and bind the textbox to that property.Count.

In your viewmodel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<int> Lister { get; set; }
```

In XAML:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lister.Count}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you click the button, refresh the textbox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lister.Add(1);
        MyTextBox.text = lister.Count.ToString();
    }
```

Note, this isn't exact code, it's there to demonstrate how it would be done.

Comment: This is doesn't sounds very WPFish with the notion of automating your bindings, listing to the model for changes.

Comment: Within the confines of what the OP posted, this is a perfectly reasonable way of accomplishing it. Though I'm a big supporter of databinding and MVVM, I find nothing wrong with this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the code-behind to do this, simply do the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lister.Add(1);

    textBox.Text = lister.Count.ToString();
}
```

I suggest you look into using WPF data binding and [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) architecture. Then you could bind the `Count` property of your list to the text in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use TextBlock instead of TextBox, as your user might thick he can changes the number of items.
2. If you want to use binding, recommend to use ObservableCollection instead, as List does not reports collection changes to the Binding engine.
3. Use Shingetsu advice.